# How to remove background image from post navigation elements?

Tags: themes, navigation

I am using a theme which shows the featured image as background image in post navigation elements (next and previous links on a single post). But I want to remove these background images.

Here is the actual code in template-tags.php file.

```
function shoreditch_post_nav_background() {
    if ( ! is_single() ) {
        return;
    }

    $previous = ( is_attachment() ) ? get_post( get_post()->post_parent ) : get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
    $next     = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );
    $css      = '';

    if ( is_attachment() && 'attachment' == $previous->post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $previous &&  has_post_thumbnail( $previous->ID ) ) {
        $prevthumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $previous->ID ), 'post-thumbnail' );
        $css .= '
            .post-navigation .nav-previous { background-image: url(' . esc_url( $prevthumb[0] ) . '); text-shadow: 0 0 0.15em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
            .post-navigation .nav-previous .post-title,
            .post-navigation .nav-previous a:focus .post-title,
            .post-navigation .nav-previous a:hover .post-title { color: #fff; }
            .post-navigation .nav-previous .meta-nav { color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); }
            .post-navigation .nav-previous a { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border: 0; }
            .post-navigation .nav-previous a:focus,
            .post-navigation .nav-previous a:hover { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }
        ';
    }

    if ( $next && has_post_thumbnail( $next->ID ) ) {
        $nextthumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $next->ID ), 'post-thumbnail' );
        $css .= '
            .post-navigation .nav-next { background-image: url(' . esc_url( $nextthumb[0] ) . '); text-shadow: 0 0 0.15em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
            .post-navigation .nav-next .post-title,
            .post-navigation .nav-next a:focus .post-title,
            .post-navigation .nav-next a:hover .post-title { color: #fff; }
            .post-navigation .nav-next .meta-nav { color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); }
            .post-navigation .nav-next a { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border: 0; }
            .post-navigation .nav-next a:focus,
            .post-navigation .nav-next a:hover { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }
        ';
    }

    wp_add_inline_style( 'shoreditch-style', $css );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shoreditch_post_nav_background' );
```

How can I remove those background images while using my child theme functions.php file, without modifying the actual file in parent theme?

Answer (score 1):

If your theme fully supports child themes copy template-tags.php to the child theme folder and edit it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can deregister that style in your child theme functions.php

```
function remove_shoreditch_background() {
    wp_deregister_style('shoreditch-style');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_shoreditch_background');
```

Or you could remove that action entirely

```
remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shoreditch_post_nav_background');
```

Or you can just overwrite the css with your own style

```
.post-navigation .nav-next {background: none !important;}
```